# RPM + How to get view of script in rpm pkg

Tags: linux, rpm

Using `rpm -qlp` I can get the content of an RPM package. How can I view the below scripts from the RPM package? (using say, `cat`, `more` or `vi`)

I want to print the following scripts (on my Linux machine) from inside the RPM package:

- `/home/Progect_ws/Progect/UFE_Install.sh`
- `/home/Progect_ws/DB_client/UFE_Install.sh`

```
#rpm -qlp CBS_Progect_WS-30_12.i386.rpm

/home/Progect_ws/Progect
/home/Progect_ws/Progect/Comverse-One-Progect-DROP1_3.5.50_TC10-Internal.zip
/home/Progect_ws/Progect/Configure_Progect.properties
/home/Progect_ws/Progect/UFE_Install.sh
/home/Progect_ws/DB_client
/home/Progect_ws/DB_client/Comverse-One-CLIENT-DROP1_3.5.50_TC10-Internal.zip
/home/Progect_ws/DB_client/Configure_client.properties
/home/Progect_ws/DB_client/UFE_Install.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rpm2cpio` but beware that it sends the cpio file to standard output, so you will want to pipe it to cpio to extract the files:

```
rpm2cpio CBS_Progect_WS-30_12.i386.rpm | cpio -idm
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [rpm2cpio](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-miscellania-rpm2cpio.html) is what you want?

It converts a `rpm` to a [cpio archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) witch you then can extract files from: `cpio -id < yourcpiofile`